# Get Current Selected Text?

Tags: string, delphi, text, selected

i need to get the current select text independently the windows (browser, text editor, games wtc.)

i found this code in stackoverflow, but it aint work.

```
 ...
 var
  Buff: array[0..65535] of char;
  ...
 function CurrentSelectedText: string;
 var
   hFocus: hWnd;
   aStart, aEnd: integer;
 begin
    //added by andrei, attach input to current thread
    AttachThreadInput(GetCurrentThreadId, GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow), true); 
    hFocus:= GetFocus;
    SendMessage(hFocus, WM_GETTEXT, 65535, integer(@buff));
    SendMessage(hFocus, EM_GETSEL, Integer(@aStart), Integer(@aEnd));
    result:= Copy(StrPas(Buff), 1+aStart, aEnd-aStart);
 end;
```

Comment: "it aint work" is not a problem description that is useful to us.

Comment: i posted the code to avoid someone postint it, or saying it's a duplicated question
i found some codes that can get the current selected text from my app, and manipulating the clipboard, but its not enough

Comment: So if you remove that code, and the sentence above it that says "it aint work", it leaves a single sentence that shows zero effort to find any information yourself or solve the problem. Once again, "it aint work" is not useful to us here. If you can't be bothered to put effort into writing your question, why would it be worth our effort to try and answer it?

Comment: @KenWhite:  Not meaning to pick up on this q specifically but I'm not sure it necessarily deserves the withering criticism. It might reflect lack of effort, but equally OTOH the OP clearly doesn't have good command of idiomatic English ("aint work").  Just saying ...

Comment: Let's back up a little bit. How doesn't it work? Do you get some error message? If so, which line fails? Regardless of English grammar, you have not told us anything about why or how it doesn't work. What do you expect it to do? What's happening instead? These are the fundamentals to asking a question, not just here, but anywhere. Ask a mechanic "It isn't working". Do you think the mechanic can fix the problem with your car?

Comment: @MartynA: My first comment was intended to point out to the user that the question provided no info. The response was "I posted it so you wouldn't say it was a duplicate", with no additional details, no more information, and no effort to improve the question. The question as stated isn't of much usefulness to future readers here. Just saying.

Comment: Which version of Delphi are you using? I ask because you are using a `char` type, which means something different depending on the Delphi version. 2009 and above `char` is Unicode (`WideChar`) whereas prior versions `char` is `AnsiChar`.

Comment: @MartynA: Perhaps, but this isn't about bedside manner, or holding a new user's hand. The site has quality guidelines, and even new users are expected to make an effort to follow them. The expected response to "you haven't explained the problem" is an edit to the question to do so, or at least to make an effort to provide details in a comment. As Jerry points out, you don't call your auto repair shop and say to the mechanic "My car aint work. How much to fix and how long will it take?" and expect any sort of answer. The pity upvoters are doing no one any favors here, either.

Comment: I still think this is a simple Unicode mix-up.

Comment: "The site has quality guidelines".  Indeed, yet all this is within an hour of the OP first posting and they've hardly had a chance to improve the q yet.  And the site has civility guidelines too.

Comment: @MartynA: And I've followed those civility guidelines. The poster had enough time to respond to my first comment with one of his own, at which point there was time to add more detail. I've been polite, pointed out the issue *twice*, and voted to close the question because it doesn't clearly state the problem with the code posted. If the OP improves the question, I'll be happy to retract that vote. I had the courtesy to ask *twice* for it to be improved before I cast that close vote. Thanks for your thoughts on the matter, though.

Answer (score 3):

There are some possibly significant problems (failing to detach the thread input, not allowing for the foreground window in the current thread, a complete absence of error checking) and a minor improvement (caching thread IDs) that can be made to your code, but in essence it should work.

I implemented this slightly modified version of your code in a **TTimer**, set to simply retrieve the current focussed window text into a **TEdit** control every 1/4 second (250 ms), and it worked exactly as expected.

```
var
  buff: array[0..65535] of char;
  thisThread: Integer;
  focusThread: Integer;
  hForeground: HWND;
  hFocus: HWND;
  a, b: Integer;
  attached: Boolean;
begin
  hForeground := GetForegroundWindow;

  // ** check hForegound is valid

  thisThread  := GetCurrentThreadID;
  focusThread := GetWindowThreadProcessID(hForeground);

  // ** check focusThread is valid

  attached := thisThread <> focusThread;
  if attached then
  begin
    AttachThreadInput(thisThread, focusThread, TRUE);

    // ** check attach was successful
  end;

  try
    hFocus := GetFocus;

    // ** check hFocus is valid/not null

    SendMessage(hFocus, WM_GETTEXT, 65535, Integer(@buff));

    // ** check SendMessage was successful

    Edit1.Text := String(@buff);

    if SendMessage(hFocus, EM_GETSEL, Integer(@a), Integer(@b)) <> 0 then
      Edit1.Text := Copy(Edit1.Text, 1 + a, b - a);

  finally
    if attached then
      AttachThreadInput(thisThread, focusThread, FALSE);
  end;
end;
```

If this code does not work for you then you can (and in any case should) add error checking code at the points that I have indicated with ** comments, to determine why it is not working in your particular case.

Note that you cannot attach a thread to itself, which is taken into account in the above modified code by only attaching (and detaching) if the two threads are different.

**The EM_GETSEL Problem:**

It is most likely possible that the problem you have is specifically with the attempt to retrieve the **Selection** range.  As indicated by the message number (**EM_...**) this is a message that only EDIT controls respond to, so if the current foreground window is not an edit control then this will almost certainly fail.

You should DEFINITELY check the success/failure of the **SendMessage( .. EM_GETSEL .. )** call, and *only* extract a range from the window text *if* you receive a valid response to that message.

I also found that trying to use **Copy()** directly on a cast version of the **buf** char array did not work.  This surprised me and might bear further investigation, but to avoid whatever problems might lie in this area, simply convert to a string first and then perform your **Copy()** to extract the range from the string.

In my working example above this is achieved by rather inefficiently assigning the converted **buf** to the **Edit1.Text** property and then using Copy() on that **Edit1.Text** property.  In practice you would use an intermediate string variable.

**WM_GETTEXT Limitations**

In your question you ask for a technique that will work for any window type, including browsers and games.  I do not think there is a universal approach that will achieve this, short of a combination of screen capture and OCR.  This is because applications such as browsers and games and even some "ordinary applications", implement window classes which render their content independent of any concept of "Window Text", as reported by **WM_GETTEXT**.  e.g. the "Window text" of a browser window is typically the browser/tab *caption* text, **not** the HTML content of the page it is currently presenting, which is maintained internally by the browser application.

If an application implements a custom window class to render some arbitrary content, then you have no way to retrieve that content without intimate knowledge of the specific application in question and/or a published mechanism supported by that application to achieve what you want.

Comment: This doesn't work on a browser page, or in a "game", or in any app that isn't the foreground (focused) window. (Not downvoting; just mentioning that it does not answer the *extremely vague* question that was asked.)

Comment: @KenWhite Very true, if it's a browser (such as the OP's first example of usage), there's no guarantee you'll get what's selected in the browser content, because that has cursor tracking entirely independent of the standards.

Comment: Indeed.  I answered the *answerable* part of the question, namely how to make the posted code work as intended, to get the text of the current foreground window, which as posted did indeed "aint work", due I think to either the assumption of a valid **EM_GETSEL** result.  I shall add clarification that this is limited to retrieving whatever text is available via WM_GETTEXT, which of course won't handle text content in exotic/sophisticated custom window class implementations, such as browsers and games.

Comment: Also have to verify is `hFocus` is valid `EDIT` widget.